# No Vector Menu Available QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I've installed QGIS 3.4 on my Mac. I don't have any vector or processing menu. In the "plugins" menu under settings, I have the following:

"The settings on this tab are only applicable for Python Plugins. No Python support detected, thus no settings available".

I've tried to troubleshoot this problem on my own in the following ways:

- re-installing QGIS.
- Under QGIS > Preferences > System, adding the following custom variable under the environment section:

  [image]

This is as directed by several other threads I have referenced but still no results. Can anyone help?